# Scala function pointer

Tags: scala

Google didn't help me with this question, I hope that doesn't mean it is not possible:

In my class I want to have a method that has a signature defined, but the body is not defined (method1)

There will be many defined methods that satisfy this signature (impl1, impl2, impl3)

When I initialise the object, I will then choose (based on some criteria) which method implementation  impl1, impl2, impl3 to assign to the function pointer method1

Basically I'm asking how I can have a function pointer that can point to any function satisfying its signature.

EDIT:

So, it turns out it is actually very straight forward:

```
var method: Int => Int = (x => x+1)

method = (x => x-1)
method = (x => x*2)
etc...
```

My problem before was that I was using "val" or "def" to define "method"

Not sure why this wasn't suggested directly. Many people favoured the way of having the function as a parameter to some secondary class then initialise that class with a specific implementation. Maybe there is something that I'm missing.

EDIT 2: I realise now that I didn't get the answer I was looking for because I didn't word my question properly, I should have said that I wanted "delegate" behaviour as it is in C#.

Comment: Why not create an abstract class with the signature then 3 child classes with the three implementations?

Comment: Function composition is more powerful that simple inheritance. By considering your code (a function, here) as data you pass to your class/function/whatever, you have a more generic way to build the composed features you need. The answer proposed by Idan Arye is a great example IMO.

Comment: @Peter yes, I ran into that when I was trying to do it. The problem is that, this is a totally different approach to what I'm trying to do, which will make me change the way I design the code. I'm thinking there should be a way to do function pointers.

Comment: _"Not sure why this wasn't suggested directly"_ because you did not mention you want this to be mutable :). You might take the fact that everyone proposed an immutable implementation as a hint to a more idiomatic solution. Also note that you can get the mutability when passing the function as parameter -- just make it a `var` and reset `foo.func = ...` if necessary.

Comment: @bluenote10 ok, let's assume everyone thought that I want it immutable. This solution I copied in my question was only presented by one person you and you used the immutable version. However, everyone else was wrapping the function in a class.. I just don't see why you would want to complicate things like that when you can just do it in a simple way. I'm trying to figure out if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: @Spacemonkey: Basically both solutions are equivalent. It simply depends on what you mean by the implementation is _chosen by some criteria_. You just have to decide whether it makes sense to let the caller make this decision or whether it is a purely internal decision.

Answer (score 6):

In Scala, functions are objects, so you can do:

```
class Foo(val func : Int => Int){
}
object Main{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val foo1=new Foo(x => x + 1)
        val foo2=new Foo(x => x + 2)
        val foo3=new Foo(x => x + 3)
        println(foo1.func(10)) // Prints 11
        println(foo2.func(10)) // Prints 12
        println(foo3.func(10)) // Prints 13
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You mean like so:

```
class Whatever(selector: Int) {

  type Signature = Int => String

  private val implUsed = selector match {
    case 1 => impl1
    case _ => impl2
  }

  private val impl1: Signature = (i: Int) => i.toString
  private val impl2: Signature = (i: Int) => i.toString + "_suffix"

  def method: Signature = implUsed

}
```

You could obviously also write the `impl`s as `def`s. Maybe a different approach based on inheritance may be preferrable though -- you may want to clarify what you are trying to achieve. While this approach is a literal solution to your request, it would be much more idiomatic to pass around the functions itself, like @Idan Arye suggested.

Comment: yeah, but then how would you reassign a different implementation to "method"?

Comment: I FOUND IT, just use "var" instead of "val"... my whole problem was that I was using "val" or "def" instead of using a "var"

Answer (score 1):

And here is not-so-elegant approach with inheritance:

```
abstract class Foo() {
  def say(): String

  protected def bark = "Woof!"
  protected def quack = "Quack!"
}

val dog = new Foo() {
  def say() = bark
}

dog.say
// res2: String = Woof!
```

Comment: yeah, I ran into this while trying to figure out the solution. However, I would rather avoid doing this.

Answer (score -1):

I would not use a method at all in this case. Just have a field that can be initialized to the specific function you want. Something like:

```
class Foo(val method1: Int => Int)

val doubler     = new Foo(2*)
val incrementer = new Foo(1+)
val absolute    = new Foo(_.abs)
val parity      = new Foo(_ % 2)
val doesNothing = new Foo(identity)

doubler.method1(-3)     // => -6
incrementer.method1(-3) // => -2
absolute.method1(-3)    // =>  3
parity.method1(-3)      // => -1
doesNothing.method1(-3) // => -3
```

Comment: Thanks, that's is an interesting workaround ! It could be actually a good idea in general to wrap all the different implementations in that same class.

Comment: Isn't this the same as Idan Arye suggested?